# Is there a name for this algebraic structure?

Tags: linear-algebra

I often come across a structure consisting of a set $P$ ("points") and a set $V$ ("vectors"), where

- $P$ has a very limited number of operations, but at least has a special element $0_P$ (the "origin")
- $V$ is a vector space (with identity $0_V$) and describes differences or distances between elements of $P$

There are two operations relating the two sets:

- $\ominus: P \times P \rightarrow V$ ("distance")
- $\oplus: P \times V \rightarrow P$ ("translation")

They follow these laws:

- $\forall p:P. p \ominus p = 0_V$
- $\forall p:P. p \oplus 0_V = p$
- $\forall p_1, p_2:P. p_1 \oplus (p_2 \ominus p_1) = p_2$

  - special case: $\forall p:P. p \oplus (0_P \ominus p) = 0_P$
- $\forall v:V. (0_P \oplus v) \ominus v = 0_V$

Here are a few examples:

- $P$: points in 3D real space, $V$: 3D real vectors
- $P$: points in time, $V$: time differences
- $P$: geographic coordinates, $V$: angular separations
- $P$: pieces of text, $V$: text editing operations
- $P$: images, $V$: image transformations

Is there a name for this structure?

Comment: Looks very much like an affine space.

Comment: @Bernard: that's it!